# seekbar onProgressChange value updates extremely slow in toast

Tags: android, android-studio, seekbar, android-toast

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        changeColor(viewOne, progress);
        changeColor(viewTwo, progress);
        changeColor(viewThree, progress);
        changeColor(viewFour, progress);
        changeColor(viewFive, progress);
    }

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

I am trying to update the value of the seekbar and display it in a toast. however, the toast updates the value extremely slowly. I would not like to use a textbox. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Using popup window.You can customize the view of popup window, like a textview to show the progress.
In method onStartTrackingTouch, show the popup window.
In method onStopTrackingTouch, dismiss the popup window.
In method onProgressChanged, change the progress.
Sample code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private SeekBar seek;
    private PopupWindow window;
    private TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        window = new PopupWindow(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setTextSize(16);
        textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        window.setContentView(textview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textview.setText("progress : " + progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        window.showAsDropDown(seek);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        window.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there no way I can accomplish this using the Toast.Make functionality? I'm just curious to learn more. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the toast at class level

```
Toast mToast;
```

Initialize the toast in `constructor` or `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

then when you need to show toast

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    mToast.setText("progress : " + progress);
    mToast.show();
}
```

now your toast updates will be instantaneous.